# Golang: reading and writing files in parallel

Tags: io, concurrency, go

I am trying to read a big file line by line, inspect and cleanse each row and write to either of two output files depending on the outcome. I am using channels for this. I am still quite new to this language so trying to build stuff by looking at examples.

I have kept a global count variable which I am printing at each 10k lines read to keep track of the progress.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "time"
    "os"
    "log"
    "sync"
    "golang.org/x/net/publicsuffix"
)


func init() {
    // Change the device for logging to stdout.
    log.SetOutput(os.Stdout)
}

var count int

// read the file line by line
// push each line (domain name) onto a channel input
// write another function which reads from the input channel
// calls the func EffectiveTLDPlusOne and saves the results
// onto channel result if successful or rejected if unsuccessful
// write another function which reads from results channel and writes to cleansed file
// write another function which reads from rejected channel and writes to rejected file


func readInputFile(fileName string, domains chan string) {
    file, err := os.Open(fileName)

    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
      // fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
      count++
      domains <- scanner.Text()
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }
}



func cleansingRoutine(domains <-chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup, results chan string, rejected chan string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for domain := range domains {

      if(count % 10000 == 0){
        fmt.Println("count", count)
      }

      // get the domain name
      // if valid, push to result channel the result
      // if invalid, push to rejected channel the domain name as input
      domainName, err := publicsuffix.EffectiveTLDPlusOne(domain)
      if err != nil {
        rejected <- domain
      } else {
        results <- domainName        
      }
    }
}



func main() {

  fmt.Println("start time", time.Now());

  concurrency := 500
  domains := make(chan string, 1000)
  results := make(chan string, 1000)
  rejected := make(chan string, 1000)

  fileName := os.Args[1]
  fmt.Println("fileName", fileName)
  go readInputFile(fileName, domains)  

  wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
  wg.Add(concurrency)

  for i := 0; i < concurrency; i++ {
      // parallel routine for cleansing
      go cleansingRoutine(domains, wg, results, rejected)
  }

  go writeToCleanFile(fileName, results)
  go writeToRejectedFile(fileName, rejected)

  wg.Wait()
  close(results)
  close(rejected)


  fmt.Println("end time", time.Now());
  return

}



func writeToCleanFile(fileName string, results chan string) {
  // write all lines to clean file
  resultFileName := fileName + ".cleansed"
  resultFile, err := os.OpenFile(resultFileName, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, os.ModeAppend)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  defer resultFile.Close()
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  for r := range results {  
    // fmt.Println("results", r)
    // write to file resultFileName
    _, err := resultFile.WriteString(r + "\n")
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }
  }
}


func writeToRejectedFile(fileName string, rejected chan string) {
  // write all lines to clean file
  rejectedFileName := fileName + ".rejected"
  rejectedFile, err := os.OpenFile(rejectedFileName, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, os.ModeAppend)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  defer rejectedFile.Close()
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  for r := range rejected {  
    // fmt.Println("rejected", r)
    // write to file rejectedFileName
    _, err := rejectedFile.WriteString(r + "\n")
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you are aware of that `writeToCleanFile` and `writeToRejectedFile` are basically the same function--you could handle different arriving request in `select`. That aside: you don't really need waiting group here, you already know how many files are going to be written: the usual pattern is to just count the responses.